# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1109 Unknown table 's0_' in field list

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm

Get the following exeption using Doctrine: `SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1109 Unknown table 's0_' in field list`

A query executed, just before the exeption, on the same table works just fine:
Note that in the mapping I hat to put quotes '`' in the column name ADR#A because of the # in the columnname

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT s0_.`ADR#A`) AS sclr0 FROM stadrp s0_
```

However, this query pops the exception.

```
SELECT DISTINCT s0_.`ADR#A` AS ADR#A0, s0_.`ADR#A` AS ADR#A1 
FROM stadrp s0_ 
ORDER BY s0_.`ADR#A` ASC 
LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: Does it work if you quote `ADR#A0` the alias?

Comment: @RoelVeldhuizen Can you check if my answer is working?

Comment: @Michael, yes, that seems to work on the commandline. I'm unsure how to fix this in the doctrine entities

Comment: @Ravinder your answer also works on the commandline

Comment: @RoelVeldhuizen Can you check the same with Doctrine?

Comment: @Ravinder as mentioned above, I still searching for a solution to do this in doctrine. Any ideas?

Comment: @RoelVeldhuizen I am handicapped at Doctrine. :(

Answer (score 0):

`#` is used to comment a statement in MySQL.
If you want it part of a label, use quotes to surround it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT s0_.`ADR#A` AS 'ADR#A0', s0_.`ADR#A` AS 'ADR#A1' 
FROM stadrp s0_ 
ORDER BY s0_.`ADR#A` ASC 
LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: Hmm. If this is wrong, downvoter should have let me know why and where I did wrong?